Jenkins 2 freestyle jobs from same repository and branch - repository alredy in use error
Hello I have small problem Im kinda new in jenkins and i have use case where i need to run 2 freestyle jobs from same gitlab repo and same branch at same time . Is it possible ?
I have error that repository is already in use and dont know if there is any option to do it.

A scenario might be that the workspace being used for both the jobs is same, in that case you might get this error. Can you check your console logs for the workspace path on your master/agent node where the dsl operations are being performed. If that is the case you could change the workspace directory and resolve the issue. If that is not the case, perhaps you should share snippets of your console output here for both the jobs.
